# Sending form after confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form, where user can delete account. It's very simple form. I want the user to confirm the deletion of the account. I have function **confirmation**. I couldn't edit it.

```
function confirmation(message, ok, cancel, callback) {
    if (!$('#confirmation').length) {
        var string = 
        'some html';
        $('<div/>').attr('id', 'confirmation').css("display", "none").html(string).appendTo('body');
    }

    var result;
    $.fancybox($('#confirmation'), {
        modal : true,
        autoSize: true,
        beforeShow: function() {
            $("#confirmation-message").text(message);
            $("#confirmation-ok-caption").text(ok);
            $("#confirmation-cancel-caption").text(cancel);

            $("#confirmation-btn-ok").unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                result = true; 
                $.fancybox.close();
                return false;
            })
            $("#confirmation-btn-cancel").unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
                result = false; 
                $.fancybox.close();
                return false;
            })
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            callback.call(this, result);
        }
    });
}
```

This code doesn't work, it doesn't send form:

```
    $(document).ready( function(){ 
        $("form").submit(function() { 
            confirmation("Delete?", "Yes", "No", function (result) {
                 if(result) $("#user-form").submit();
            });
            return false;
        }) 
    });
```

How should I edit my code?
**UPD** if I change `return false;` by `return true` form is sent always!

Comment: "This code doesn't work". What doesn't work about it?

Comment: It doesn't send form

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Does the submit() execute? Does it give an error in your console?

Comment: I try replace `$("#user-form").submit();` by`console.log(1)` and console.log works

Comment: You're missing semicolons on the `bind("click"...` multiline statments, you might want to add those just to be safe.

Comment: Please confirm that the html for the form is: `<form id='user-form'>`

Comment: Exactly what happens when you click the 'Yes' button - does the confirmation disappear?  Or is there still a confirmation window?   Because it looks like you're recursively calling your `submit` handler.

Comment: Form has `id='user-form'`. After I click Yes the confirmation dissappear and nothing happens

Comment: There is not enough information posted to help you. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: re: the "UPD" - the `return false` stops the default submit, which would occur before your confirmation dialog has been displayed (as the dialog is async).  So you need this.

Comment: Try adding another button wired up to the confirmation and hiding the submit button.

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: @freedomn-m thx, I added tag a and hid submit, after click a, I checking result and sending form.

Comment: @Vadim.K, did you check the solution in my answer?

Comment: @Dekel Function confirmation is stored in another file and I can't change it. I found solution this problem  through `.trigger`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having an infinite loop:

When the form is submitted you are
`(1)` Running the `confirmation` function to validate the form, and if everything is ok you are
`(2)` Trigger the `submit` using `$("#user-form").submit();`, which cause the browser to go back to `(1)`, and this loop will never end.

There are several ways to solve this. I guess the fastest way is to have a global variable that will tell you if the form was validated, and if so - return `true` inside the `submit` function before calling the `confirmation`:

```
var formConfirmed = false;
function confirmation(message, ok, cancel, callback) {
...
```

Inside the submit function:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    $("form").submit(function() { 
        if (formConfirmed) {
            return true;
        }
```

Don't forget to set `formConfirmed = true` inside the `fancybox` code.